# Winforms ComboBox only fire event when item has changed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `ComboBox` with several items. I have added an event handler to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. Suppose, the list has two items, A and B. If the currently selected item is A and the user changes it to B then the event is fired and that's OK. However, if the user clicks on the `ComboBox` and clicks on A again (meaning the item has not actually changed) the event is still fired. I would like for the event to only be fired if the item has definitely changed, or something which will allow me to accomplish this.

Comment: cmbReportTypes.SelectedIndexChanged += (a, b) => SelectedReport = ((ReportItem) cmbReportTypes.SelectedItem).CreateReport();

That is the event. Pretty simple in itself. I just want it fired ONLY when the index has changed. Example: If the index has changed from 0 to 1 then it is to be fired. If the index is "changed" from 0 to 0 then I don't want the event to be fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding the event handler to the TextChanged event instead of SelectedIndexChanged has solved my problem. This works in my case because I can be sure that no two items in the ComboBox (which is a dropdown list) will have the same text.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. In my case TextChanged strangely fires only on form load when I set the DataSource property.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't plan change `ComboBox` selection diagrammatically try use `SelectionChangeComitted`.

Answer (score 3):

Better to incapsulate this logic in class derived from ComboBox (ComboBoxEx in my example)

```
private class ComboBoxEx : System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    {
        Int32 _lastIndex = -1;
        protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_lastIndex == -1)
            {
                _lastIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
                base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
            }
            else
                if (_lastIndex != this.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
                    _lastIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
                }
        }
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
public Form1()
    {
        var combobox = new ComboBoxEx() { DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList };
        combobox.Items.Add("Item 1");
        combobox.Items.Add("Item 2");
        combobox.Items.Add("Item 3");
        this.Controls.Add(combobox);
        combobox.SelectedIndexChanged += OnIndexChanged;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Index changed");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you mean:

```
int intIndex; //Global Variable
//In your ComboBox_SelectedIndex Changed event
if(myComboBox.SelectedIndex != intIndex) 
{
   //your code
   intIndex = myComboBox.SelectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to databind the combobox to a property in a model class. The model should then implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged (and firing it correctly, so only when a value is changed). You can then use the PropertyChanged event to handle a change in the selection of the control, and this event would only be fired when an actual change happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a int variable with the SelectedIndex of your ComboBox, then you can check if the variable has the same value as the index.
If yes, don't do anything, else do the stuff.

```
int lastIndex = myComboBox.SelectedIndex;
```

Then in the SelectedIndexChangedEvent:

```
if(lastIndex != myComboBox.SelectedIndex){
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your **InitializeComponent()**, put this in your combobox

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
   ///combobox
   ///This line will triger if the combobox has changed
   this.combobox.SelectedIndexChanged += System.EventHandler(this.comboboxChanged);
}
```

Then in your main method create the combobox method like

```
private string previousValue;

Private void comboboxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (combobox.Text == "A" && previousValue == "A")
        {
            //Do nothing
            previousValue = "A";
        }
    else if (combobox.Text == "B" && previousValue == "B")
        {
            //Do Nothing
            previousValue = "B";
        }
    else if (combobox.Text == "A")
        {
            //Do Something
            previousValue = "A";
        }
    else if (combobox.Text == "B")
        {
            //Do Something
            previousValue = "B";
        }
}
```

Comment: For the sake of future readers, can you explain why this works.

Comment: @litelite i have edited my answer. Still the event is firing, but what OP want's to accomplish is to do stuff if the value change A changes to B. If value A changes to A, then do nothing.